# Wordpress sIte doesn't work after transfer from local server (database issue?)

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have developed a custom WordPress theme with custom woocommerce shop locally with MAMP. It works great.

I have uploaded all the files to the server, revised the config file for new database.
Created the database, exported it from my local with in the phpMyadmin and imported it to the online server database. The database was 16MB so it didn't import well as one file or as separate tables so I used bigdump to import it. and it looked like it worked.

after that I changed the URLs to the new ones from in wp_options table in phpMyadmin of the new db.

However the site now displays error lines and the WordPress Admin Bar is missing from the top.
In addition to that the Products tab of woocommerce is missing and the plugin admin area is empty. I also cannot install plugins. etc' It all doesn't function well.

I'm guessing this is a bad transfer of the database but I have no clue.

[This is the website](https://www.livhaley.com)

```
Error lines examples:
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/254369/webspace/httpsdocs/wp-content/plugins/wp-pagenavi/scb/Options.php on line 46
```

Also...

```
Warning: call_user_func_array(): First argument is expected to be a valid callback,

'woocommerce_demo_store' was given in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/254369/webspace/httpsdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 405
```

Any advise on figuring out what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't import the data by exporting all tables through phpMyAdmin. In the process you will overwrite the tables that were created for the new wordpress installation, with its own values for options such as siteurl, bloginfo etc.

So re-install Wordpress on the new server, to start again clean. Don't overwrite the tables it auto-generates.

Login to your development wordpress dashboard, go to Tools > Export and select all content, including all linked files. Go to new Wordpress, go to tools > Import, select Wordpress, install the plugin, choose the file you exported and you should be all set.

You will need to update some URL's that might not get updated within your posts/pages. You might also need to update catid's in your code, as the imported categories will get assigned new values.

Comment: Does this work when trying to import from a file exported on a local server and not online? doesn't it try to access the site it is importing from in the process?
(I think it asks if to "download all files and attachements" no? or should I no check yes on that one?)

Comment: Yes it works in all cases, as long as your are exporting content and then importing it from one Wordpress site to another.
Yes do check "download all files and attachments", because it will transfer all the posts, categories and pages by default, but if you select to download all files, it will transfer all files in your media library too. It will maintain the images or videos you might have embedded inside your posts or pages. All these files are basically the ones inside the wp-content/uploads folder.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the website is online or not, because all it is doing is exporting only the content from phpMyAdmin that doesn't overwrite the properties of the new wordpress installation. So it takes the select rows from wp_posts table, and wp_users etc, that it needs to transfer the content. 
It does not try to access the website you are importing from, because everything it needs is in the exported file. So when you upload that, it already has everything it needs, regardless whether the website it imported from was online or local.

Comment: I have tried this and my export file is 10MB. here is the error i get:
Sorry, there has been an error.
File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

Comment: Please read my edits in main post above (there was no room for it here in comments). Thanks
Edit: and appearnatly i somehow edited your answer instead of my question and now can't remove it. damn its been a loooong day.

Comment: Ok if anyone decides to go the route of importing through a fresh wp install as oppose to importing the database itself. this is the solution, otherwise "download file attachments" won't work:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/import-post-thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

James - regarding the import error, this is because the server you are trying to import the file on has a limit on the size of files it can import.

Go into the root folder of your server (the one in which wp-content, wp-includes etc folders are in), and either edit the php.ini file currently there, or upload a new one. You can download this sample file: http://www.reallylinux.com/docs/php.ini and upload it. Edit the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize value to 50MB or something: post_max_size = 50M

This will fix the import problem.

For the plugin error, copy the plugin files from wp-content from your dev server and import them into the live server, it should work.

Comment: I have done this and what happens now is that the import uploads the file and then when it supposed to bring up the screen where I chose to import the users (or assign them to existing) and check the box to download attachments, it just has a blank screen and gets stuck there...

Comment: I think it might be an error with the importing then. Do you see any of the posts/pages imported already? Then it might be in the middle of import where it fails. Either way, maybe you should setup a new db and install wordpress and import from scratch. With a lot of import attempts and rewriting db, maybe something was corrupted.